# Are technically wrong answers and comments allowed on physics.SE?

Tags: support

I flagged some comments and answers as technically wrong but these flags were declined and moderator's reply was:"flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

How I am supposed to notify the technical inaccuracies? I have got privilege to comment everywhere and I left some comments on the answers which have some technical inaccuracies.

> Is it ok to leave such a comment?

Comment: They shouldn't be allowed; but they are, unfortunately. http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4751/23119

Comment: Bear in mind that not everyone will agree with your judgement in this area

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you indicate that an answer is wrong is by commenting to point out why it's wrong, as you did, and by downvoting, which requires 125 reputation.

The way to indicate that a comment is wrong, if it's a recent comment, is to post a followup comment explaining why. If it's an old comment, you might as well just flag it as obsolete.

Comment: -1. Your answer is wrong, because you recently banned me for doing exactly that.

Comment: No I didn't. We _never_ suspend anyone for pointing out something they think is wrong.

Comment: So why did my comment pointing out he was wrong get deleted? And you didnt respond to my Message asking for clarification of suspension? Also you were saying that I were esposing non-mainstream physics or some such, when all I did was to quote 3 sentences of wikipedia and which is found in every textbook. I still dont understand why I was banned

Comment: You weren't _banned_, you were _suspended_. After all, you're still here, and nobody would really care that you'd ever gotten suspended unless you brought it up. Since you asked: normally I wouldn't discuss it, but in this case I'll tell you that your comments were deleted because they were rude, and that also triggered your suspension. Nobody responded to your message because we didn't think you'd believe whatever explanation we gave you, and also because you yelled at us - even your reply to the message telling you about your rudeness was rude.

Comment: @AllahAbdulalaGustavoElFakir: Well, you can say what you want, but you where the one who was wrong, and you had refused to listen to anna v's correction, and even posted your own wrong answer, acting as if you were different people (i.e. "Thank you. I will accept this answer in two days.") and avoided replying on-topicly, and diverted the topic when someone commented on that "answer". Not talking about SE, but I wouldn't care whether you were rude, but you were wrong and stubborn, which is a (not by SE policy) right, good enough reason, to have you suspended, or even deleted.

Answer (score 6):

If you spot something wrong, you have a few options:

**If it's a wrong answer:**

- If you see a way of fixing the answer without changing it much, you
  can edit it.
- If you don't see an easy way of fixing it you can comment on it, or
  downvote, preferably both.
- You can post a correct answer and if appropriate, address what was
  wrong about the other answer(s).

**If it's a wrong comment:**

- You can respond to the comment with a comment (use your best judgment
  with this).
- If you think you can answer the question and comment address the comment, leave an answer.

**If it's a wrong question:**

- If you see a way of editing the question to fix it without breaking the original question, consider editing it.
- You could leave a comment explaining what's wrong with the question.
- You could flag the question or vote to close it.
- You could search the site for related or duplicate questions and leave them in the comments.
- You could leave an answer explaining why the question is wrong but addressing the general idea of the question if appropriate.

Comment: I'm unsure what a wrong question looks like, though.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: philosophy.